# Displaying only the required rows in FPDF

Tags: fpdf

Yet again would require some assistance.I am currently generating PDFs using FPDF.

This I have successfully carried out without any issues, what I have is a

particular situation which is not producing the expected result which I actually

know from where it is coming.

The table I am displaying has its source of course from an SQL statement and is a UNION of multiple other tables.

This is not saved in the database and has multiple rows. What I am trying to achieve is that from a table of 1000 entries I only make visible those rows which fall under a certain criteria through conditional statement. This is presently achieved however the problem I am experiencing since the table spans through a lot of pages the chosen items are not collated in one page but dispersed through all the pages where actually the item is situated/located through the table.

What I actually want to achieve is those items deemed suitable through the conditional statement are collated on one page and all lines attributed to non visible rows are removed.

Visually and simplistically I require some thing like this:

```
======================
ID    DESC     VALUE
---------------------
0     A         3
1     B         1
2     C         2
3     D         5
======================
```

Presently if I have a condition where all values less than 3 it will be displayed as follows:

```
======================
ID    DESC     VALUE
---------------------

1     B         1
2     C         2

=====================
```

Note the upper and lower empty rows.

What I want to achieve is the following:

```
======================
ID    DESC     VALUE
---------------------
1     B         1
2     C         2
======================
```

i.e. removal of blank rows.

The problem comes from the sql statement since i am delivering x amount of rows and only deciding what to show and not show depending on the criteria.

In this instance I cannot modify the sql statement since the conditional statement used is based on variable parameters which the user decides.

Is there a way in FPDF to move up the rows or remove thus avoiding the in-between rows?

I am very sorry if this is not clear enough but cannot deliver a snippet cause the coding is quite huge here.

Let me know if you can assist. and as always thank you.

Answer (score 0):

issue resolved by a continue statement. Thanks anyway and for the next time.

Kindest Regards
Ryan